# Almacenar en una variable un dato de la opcion marcada en un select para luego mostrarlo dinamicamente

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

tengo un select en donde las opciones las completo con los datos de los productos que tengo almacenados en mi bbdd. El código es el siguiente:

```
    <select name="p1" id="select1" required />
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Elige un producto</option>
    <?php   
    foreach($productos as $prod)
    {
    echo "<option value=".$prod['id'].">".$prod['nombre']." (".$prod['precio']." €)</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

Lo que necesito es almacenar el valor de $prod['precio'] de la opcion seleccionada, para despues realizar una operacion aritmética y mostrarlo en otro lugar de la página dinámicamente.

En alguna ocasión anterior empleé el evento onChange para lanzar una funcion js y mostrar el value seleccionado pero no se si es posible mezclandolo con php. Además en este caso el "value" corresponde a otro dato que debo guardar en la bbdd ¿Cuál seria la opcion adecuada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="p1" id="select1" required />
    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Elige un producto</option>
    <?php foreach($productos as $prod): ?>
    <option precio='<?php echo $prod['id'] ?>' value='<?php echo $prod['id'] ?>'><?php echo $prod['nombre']; ?></option>;
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Yo lo haría así es más limpio, con jquery ($("#select1").attr('precio');) puedes calcular el precio y guardarlo en otra variable dentro del campo.

También lo que puedes hacer es procesarlo con PHP. Preguntas en tu BBDD por el ID y calculas el precio.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando la extensión JSON y siguiendo la idea de como tenés el código se me ocurre lo siguiente:

```html
<select name="p1" id="select1" required />
 <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Elige un producto</option>
 <?php   
  foreach($productos as $prod)
  {
   echo "<option value='{".htmlspecialchars('"'.$prod['id'].'"', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8').":".htmlspecialchars('"'.$prod['precio'].'"', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."}'> ".$prod['nombre']." ( ".$prod['precio']." €) </option>";
  }
 ?>
</select>
```

El código anterior deja a cada "value" de la siguiente forma:

```
"{"id_producto":"precio_producto"}"
```

Luego usando la extensión [JSON](http://php.net/manual/es/book.json.php) y su función [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) (el id del producto así como el precio tienen que estar entre comillas dobles para poder utilizar json_decode):

```
json_decode($_POST['p1'], true)
```

Esto lo que hace es devolver un array asociativo de la forma:

```
[id_producto] => precio_producto
```

Con esto obtenes el ID y precio del producto del select de manera relativamente sencilla. Espero que te sirva, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias por las respuestas.
Al final lo he hecho con jquery, algo similar a lo que sugiere @Subiendo.

```
<select name="p1" id="select1" required />
<option precio="0" selected="true" disabled="disabled">Elige un producto</option>
<?php foreach($productos as $prod): ?>
<option class="opcion" precio='<?php echo $prod['precio'] ?>' value='<?php echo $prod['id'] ?>'><?php echo $prod['nombre']; ?></option>;
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Pero le añadí una clase a las opciones del select para que cuando se clickee alguna me diga el precio.

El js quedaría así:

```
$('.opcion').on('click', function(){
var $precioSeleccionado = $(this).attr('precio');
});
```